# How to implement comments section in database

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a website with Articles (unique by `articleID`), each with comments, and comments can have replys to comments indefinitely. How should this be implemented and queried in a SQL database? Should Comments have their own table and simply be added row by row, regardless of how deep the replies go? What is the standard approach to implementing this in a database?

Example:
**My Article** (ID:5)

This is the text to my article

**Comments:**

***User 10:*** I hate this article (User_ID: 10, Comment_ID: 1)

        ***User 21:*** No, its an ok article. (User_ID: 21, Comment_ID: 4)

                ***User 54:*** You must be crazy. (User_ID: 54, Comment_ID: 6)

        ***User 76:*** I hate this article too (User_ID: 76, Comment_ID: 12)

***User 23:*** Wow this article is bad (User_ID: 23, Comment_ID: 2)

Should the comments table just look like:

Comment_ID: 1

Comment: I hate this article

Date: 1/1/2016

User_ID: 10

Reply_TO_ID: null

Comment_ID: 4

Comment: No, its an ok article.

Date: 1/2/2016

User_ID: 21

Reply_TO_ID: 1

...and then just do a query for each comment, looking for comments that have a `Reply_TO_ID` matching that comment and do it recursively?

Comment: Multiple ways to solve this, but I think the article [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) is a good start.

Comment: Adjacency list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list

Answer (score 0):

Better create two tables ; one for comments and another for answers/reply.
articleID is the common key between comments and article table and replay_id is the common key between answers/reply table and comments table.